# Java 8 Streams peek api

Tags: java, java-8

I tried the following snippet of Java 8 code with `peek`.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bender", "Fry", "Leela");
list.stream().peek(System.out::println);
```

However there is nothing printed out on the console. If I do this instead:

```
list.stream().peek(System.out::println).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I see the following which outputs both the peek as well as foreach invocation.

```
Bender
Bender
Fry
Fry
Leela
Leela
```

Both `foreach` and `peek` take in a  `(Consumer<? super T> action)`
So why is the output different?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) mentions the following:

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

`peek` being an intermediate operation does nothing. On applying a terminal operation like `foreach`, the results do get printed out as seen.

Comment: _peek being an intermediate operation does nothing_ - Why would one call  method that does absolutely nothing?

Comment: @zeroflagL, It is an intermediate method which means it is lazy. It wont do anything unless a terminal operation is invoked on it which would result in some computation to be performed. From what i read so far, `peek` is especially useful when you are debugging some terminal operation and want to find out what the previous state looked like before the terminal operation gets applied on it. You can use `peek` to print out the elements of the stream in that case.

Comment: There's a difference between doing nothing and being lazy. Furthermore `peek` immediately returns a new stream, which is not nothing either.

Comment: My comment (and the original question) was more in terms of execution of the operation that is specified within it....

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for `peek` says

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream.
>   This is an intermediate operation.

You therefore have to do something with the resulting stream for `System.out.println` to do anything.

Answer (score 6):

From the docs on [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for the peek method:

> ...additionally performing the provided action on each element **as elements are consumed** from the resulting stream.

Answer (score 0):

Streams in Java-8 are lazy, in addition, say if there are two chained operations in stream one after the other, then the second operation begins as soon as first one finishes processing a unit of data element (given there is a terminal operation in the stream).

This is the reason why you can see repeated name strings getting output.