# How to use Streams api peek() function and make it work?

Tags: java, java-stream

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586014/java-8-streams-peek-api), `peek()` is lazy it means we should somehow activate it. In fact, to activate it to print something out to the console I tried this :

```
Stream<String> ss = Stream.of("Hi","Hello","Halo","Hacker News");
ss.parallel().peek(System.out::println);
System.out.println("lol"); // I wrote this line to print sth out to terminal to wake peek method up
```

But that doesn't work and the output is :

```
lol
```

Thus, how can I make the `peek` function actually work?

If there is no way to that so whats the point of using `peek`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) on a stream for it to execute (peek is not terminal, it is an intermediate operation, that returns a new Stream), e.g. count():

```
Stream<String> ss = Stream.of("Hi","Hello","Halo","Hacker News");
ss.parallel().peek(System.out::println).count();
```

Or replace `peek` with `forEach` (which is terminal):

```
    ss.parallel().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Using `.count()` to invoke `peek()` before counting the elemnts?

Comment: @ehsan peek in your case is a poor choice, better is `forEach` (and yes, peek will execute before the count will be returned).

Comment: Sure , but `.count()` isn't a waste of resources?

Comment: Yeah, kind of, but peek is used as a side effect of main stream flow, so you have to have some kind of terminal operation, `count` is just an example, you could use any other if you want to have `peek` in place.

Answer (score 1):

peek() method uses Consumer as parameter which means that **potentially you can mutate the state of the incoming element**. **At the same time Java documentation says that peek should be mostly used for debugging purposes.** It is an intermediate operator and requires a terminal operator like forEach.

```
stream().peek(Consumer).forEach(Consumer);
```